# How can I make a Python while loop continue only if exactly one condtition is true?

Tags: python, debugging, while-loop, logical-operators

If I write `or`, the loop should continue only if one statement is true, but when two conditions are true as if I used the `and` logical operator. If I write `and`, then it runs when one condition is true.

I want it to run when only one of the conditions of the while loop is true.

How could I solve this bug?

```py
import random

def game():
    import random
    answer = random.randint(1, 100)
    print('Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!')
    print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.')
    print(f'Pssst, the correct answer is {answer}.')
    diff = input('Choose a difficulty. Type e for easy h for hard:\n ')
    lives = 10
    if diff == 'h':
        lives = 5
    end = 0
    while end == 0 or lives != 0:
        print(f'You have {lives} attempts remaining to guess the number.')
        guess = int(input('Make a guess: '))
        if guess > answer:
            lives -= 1
            print("Too high.")
        if guess < answer:
            lives -= 1
            print('Too low.')
        if guess == answer:
            print(f'You got it! The answer was {answer}.')
            end = 1
```

Comment: There are a number of problems with your question.
The two most obvious ones are:
1. It's hard to understand what you are asking.
2. The code snippet you inserted is not formatted. Which makes it even harder to understand your question.
(+1. It looks suspiciously like a homework assignment but this might not be the case)
Keep in mind that you are basically asking people a favor to look at your problem.
No one is going to bother to look at it and answer if you have not bothered to format and phrase your question correctly.
This may also explain the downvote on your question.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, find the first point in the execution where the value of a variable or subexpression is not what you expect & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please look at the formatted version of your post before you publish. See the edit help & advanced help re block & inline formats for code & quotes, etc. Please use standard spelling & punctuation. Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Your writing is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Comment: `while end == 0 or lives != 0` stops when `end != 0 and lives == 0`. Decide when you want to stop. Then loop `while not` that. PS De Morgan's laws say `!(x one_of_AND_or_OR y)` is `!x the_other_one !y`. PS To record whether something is so use a boolean.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want to keep the loop running if and only if there is only 1 and exactly 1 True in `[end == 0, lives != 0]`.Try this:`while (end == 0 and lives == 0) or (end != 0 and lives != 0)` or `bool(end) is bool(lives)`.
TIP: For an `int` object `i`, if and only if `i == 0`  , `bool(i)` will be False. Otherwise it will be `True`.